# DropDown list in Android 4.2 doesn't work, in Android 2.2 works well

Tags: android, spinner, android-2.2-froyo, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a Spinner that works well in Android 2.2, but in Android 4.2 doesn't work.

I tried to debug with a virtual android, but when I click to the Spinner, its does nothing in the debug window and the virtual android loses focus.

Comment: there is an incompatibility between the version 2.2 and 4.2 in the component "Spinner"?

Comment: What about LogCat what are the errors reported ?

Comment: LogCat reports 0 errors

Answer (score 1):

Try This-

```
    Spinner spinnerQuantity;
        spinnerQuantity=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerQuantity);
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapterQuantity = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,qtyArray);
                adapterQuantity.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerQuantity.setAdapter(adapterQuantity);
            
         spinnerQuantity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) {
                        
                        pos=position;
                        System.out.println("selected position:"+pos);
                        if(pos!=0){
                            editItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            spinnerQuantity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            textSelectQyt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                        else{
                            editItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            spinnerQuantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            textSelectQyt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
        
                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //do nothing
                    }
                });
```

And in your xml-

```
 <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerQuantity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text_quantity"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_quantity"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:prompt="@string/select_quantity" />
```

It should work I have tested on all version..